# Relate records from the same custom object

Tags: custom-object, relationships, master-detail

I have a custom object called 'Events'. I would like to create a relationship that allows Event records to be related to other Event records. Is this possible using standard customisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Just add a lookup field on the event__c object to lookup to itself.

Comment: Is there anyway to add multiple Event records to an Event record? A lookup relationship only allows the user to select one record.

Comment: You would have to create a junction object with a master detail to Event and a lookup to event in order to be able to relate multiple objects to the same object type

Answer (score 2):

To relate multiple event objects, you need to create a new object called something like `EventRelationship`. You then create two master-detail relationships on that object to `Event` - if the relationship is directional you could call these `From` and `To`. (By making the relationships master-detail, the relationship object is automatically deleted if either of the Event objects are deleted.)

You can then add EventRelationship objects as a related list to the Event layout, showing either the "From" or the "To" or both. And the "New" buttons allow you to wire up new relationships.

(Salesforce counts any SObject row as using 2k bytes of storage space even though you might imaging a simple relationship object would only use a few tens of bytes; only an issue if you have a large number of relationship objects.)

Comment: Have you tried your solution .I dont think we can have master detail on any object to event

Comment: @MohithShrivastava The question says its a custom object Event; are you thinking of the standard Event object?

Comment: cool.Should work if custom object .